# Creating custom prop while using (Material UI) withStyles instead of the default prop `classes` in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

So, whenever I use `withStyles`, it creates a default prop named - (this.props.{**classes**}) and if I use withTheme it creates -(this.props.{**theme**}).

### Question 1

theme prop here does it contain theme data related to the MaterialUI Components I am using or just theme data for all components?

### Question 2

My 2nd Question is, what if I want to store these props into a single object such as `*this.props.header.classes and this.props.header.theme*`. Is it possible to do this?

### Question 3

My 3rd question is, How are the class names defined internally? According to me, they might be using some library like `classnames` or `clsx`. Am I stating correct?

### Example

Here is the classname which was created for a component appBar - `App-appBar-2`

- I think appBar because that is the name of style key in the styles object.
- Does the number `2` here has any significance?

Here is the snippet of styles

```
const headerStyles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
   ...
   ...
)}
```

What I have -

```
props = {
 classes,
 theme,
 ...
}
```

What I plan to have is -

```
props = {
 header: {
  classNames: classes,
  theme: theme
 },
 ...
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: it's the whole theme provided by your theme provider upstream.
Answer 2: That would be only possible  by using a second higher order Component (not recommend), which wraps it's props into seperated header props.
Answer 3: The class name composition is mentioned in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#class-names)
Hope this helps. Happy coding.